# Single product backlog item to be shared on two ADO boards

Tags: azure, azure-devops, agile

We have a shared work item where two teams work together.
is it possible to create a common PBI which can be visible on both the boards ?
This work item type is dependency.

Google
and
self-exploration.

Answer (score 0):

To work with PBIs, a team should be an owner of these PBIs. In your case, you may just copy the current PBI and add a team-specific description. Then each team adds its own estimate and child tasks.

If you what to use one shared PBIs, that may be not so a manageable structure... Let's say the first team will be an owner and adds tasks for the second team. In this case, the first team sees the full structure in the backlog:

[image]

and only its tasks in the sprint:

[image]

The second team can find only its task in the sprint as unparented:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the sprint/area path configuration of the teams is defined. If both team share their area path, then the PBI will show up on both boards.